# Activator.CreateInstance() troubles

Tags: c#, class, instantiation, activator

I have a factory that is supposed to create objects that inherit from class Foo at run-time. I would think that System.Activator.CreateInstance's return type was the same as the type of an object it's creating, but judging from the following error message, its return type is Object.

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'cs_sandbox.Foo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    F:\projects\cs_sandbox\Form1.cs 46  24  cs_sandbox

OK, so maybe I *am* missing a cast, but

```
return (t)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

results in yet another error message, which -- I must admit -- makes no sense to me:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\projects\cs_sandbox\Form1.cs 45  25  cs_sandbox

And here's my code:

```
class Foo { }
class FooChild1 : Foo { }
class FooChild2 : Foo { }

class MyFactory
{
    public static Foo CreateInstance(string s)
    {
        Type t;
        if (s.StartsWith("abcdef"))
        {
            t = typeof(FooChild1);
            return System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        }
        else
        {
            t = typeof(FooChild2);
            return System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this code? Or, if it's not fixable, what are other ways of creating objects that inherit from a specific class at run-time?

Comment: You mean `Bar` and `Meh` inherit from `Foo`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to cast the returned object to `Foo` type. It doesn't make sense to cast it to a type defined in a variable. It should be known by the compiler, as the whole point of casting through the inheritance hierarchy is satisfying compiler's static type checking.

```
return (Foo)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

There's a generic version, `System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>`, which creates a known type (not a type variable but a type argument or a statically known type, in the latter case, it doesn't make much sense though):

```
return System.Activator.CreateInstance<FooChild1>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use to UnWrap() method after activating, like described on MSDN:

```
// Creates an instance of MyType defined in the assembly called ObjectHandleAssembly.
ObjectHandle obj = domain.CreateInstance("ObjectHandleAssembly", "MyType");

// Unwrapps the proxy to the MyType object created in the other AppDomain.
MyType testObj = (MyType)obj.Unwrap();
```

As described [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx). Furthermore, I had to use parameters like this:

```
    ObjectHandle obj = domain.CreateInstance("Other.Assembly.Name", "Full.Class.Namespace.ClassName");
```

Answer (score 1):

### After you changed code

Just cast your results to `Foo` like

```
return System.Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Foo;
```

or

```
return (Foo)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

The first one is a bit more robust because you won't get an exception in case cast is not possible. It will simply return `null`. But it depends what you want.

### Before you changed code

<strike>Have you tried generics?</strike>

```
public static OutType CreateInstance<OutType>(string s)
{
    Type t;
    if (s.StartsWith("abcdef"))
    {
        t = typeof(Bar);
        return System.Activator.CreateInstance(t) as OutType;
    }
    else
    {
        t = typeof(Meh);
        return System.Activator.CreateInstance(t) as OutType;
    }
}
```

<strike>But you do have a problem. In your existing static method you are trying to return `Bar` and `Meh` that aren't related to `Foo` in any way. This will always be an exception unless your method also returns an object or a common ancestor type (as in casting).</strike>

To control even more internal types you could define more than one generic type that your method would use internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably do this:

```
public static Foo CreateInstance(string objectIdentifer)
{
   if (objectIdentifier == "Child1")
   {
      return (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance("Foo.FooChild1, FooChild1");
   }
   else
   {
      return (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance("Foo.FooChild1, FooChild2");
   }
}
```

My point is that in this code, the CreateInstance method has no direct reference to the assembly or assemblies containing FooChild1 and FooChild2. In the original code, you create a type by explicitly naming FooChild1 and FooChild2, so you might as well just new them instead of activating them.

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct is:

```
public static Foo CreateInstance(string objectIdentifer)
{
   if (objectIdentifier == "Child1")
   {
      return (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Foo.FooChild1, FooChild1"));
   }
   else
   {
      return (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Foo.FooChild1, FooChild2"));
   }
}
```

Hope that can help you