# Access to methods in Object type

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like the following (that was typed off the top of my head so it might not be 100% accurate, but it should get the point across) in csharp, but I'm not really sure how.

```
class Test
{
  private __construct() {}

  public static function GetInstance($name)
  {
      if (file_exists($name . ".php"))
      {
            return new $name();
      }
      else
      {
            return null;
      }
  }
}
```

I know how to get the object I want back based on the input, but I have to return an Object, because I'm not sure which one the caller will request. However, when I have no idea how to get access to the methods in the returned Object.

Comment: This will not compile. You can't have a dollar sign in an identifier in C#. And what is "function"?

Comment: That was an example in PHP for what I want to accomplish in C#.

Comment: In c# you probably won't have any code files for your classes around when you run the program. I think it would be better if you describe what you want your code to do. Create an object of a certain type, given the type name? I'll post an example of that.

Comment: Be prepared for a bumpy road.  True OOP is going to slap you in the face for a while.  And then you figure it out, that's big.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, but I figured it out. The code spinet is basically how you create a factory in PHP. The way I ended up doing it in C# works, but it might not be "correct" I really don't know. It's still loosely coupled enough for my dll to work and not cause issues. I will say going back to C# (I haven't touched in several years) has been a fun experience and I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your pseudo code correctly you will have to cast the resulting object to the type that you are expecting so you can access the public methods of that type:

```
Foo myFoo = (Foo) Test.GetInstance("Foo");
string bar = myFoo.Bar();
```

Also check the [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method which basically does what your `GetInstance` method wants to do.

Comment: Then wouldn't the class calling that have to know the names of the other classes? I'm wanting the calling class to have no knowledge of the group of classes that share the same interface.  From the above example I could have 2 different classes that can get returned that share the same interface, but have different logic for the same methods.

Comment: @William: If they all share the same interface just declare your method to return the type of the interface, no cast needed then.

Comment: oh I didn't realize I could do that. Thank you! I'd give you 100 points if I could!

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly I think you want to create an object by type name. There are a number of ways to do this. This is one example:

```
public static class Test
{
    public object CreateInstance(string typeName)
    { 
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

This assumes the typeName is a full type name including namespace, and that this type has a default (no argument) constructor. Otherwise the method will fail. Use for example like this (you have to cast to User your type in order to access the methods in the User type.

```
User user = (User)Test.CreateInstance("Some.Namespace.User");

// Now methods and propertes are available in user
Console.WriteLine("User name: "+user.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484577/activator-createinstance-troubles) thread also helps. [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/) is some more reflection examples.

```
// create instance of class DateTime
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DateTime));


// create instance of DateTime, use constructor with parameters (year, month, day)
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DateTime),
                                                       new object[] { 2008, 7, 4 });
```